# login into new unity desktop

Tags: unity, server

A couple of months ago I setup a brand new Ubuntu 16.04 server with samba running to give me a simple file server on my LAN at home. Server can be accessed by several W10 pcs, several Android devices and also a couple of Chromecasts. All of these working happily.

I also use, from my main W10 PC, Webmin just to monitor that the server is working and to administer package updates. I use Putty from the same PC to do the odd command line things on the Ubuntu server including occasionally rebooting it.

In the last week I've used the Putty client to add the Unity desktop unto the 16.04 server apparently successfully. I can still see the server from both Webmin and Putty sessions.

When I connect a monitor and keyboard directly on the server machine there is the Unity desktop with the same user that I use for Putty sessions asking for a password to login....... Which it then REJECTS!!!

Can any kind soul point me in the direction for where I need to go to get out of this bind please?

TIA

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* what happens when you try to login - is there an 'invalid password' message, or does it just loop back to the login screen?

Comment: Hi steeldriver, thank you for your reply. I've just tried it again and it's the loop back case ie

Comment: sorry about that one steeldriver it got away before I'd finished :-) and then the subsequent edit time me out - full text appears below in the next post